# AWS IAM Policy EC2 and RDS by Tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

The goal is to find out if it's possible to create an EC2 role for letting users launch new EC2 and RDS instances with full admin access for resources tagged with sf_env:dev in the us-west-2 region. Is it possible to do all of this? If so, what am I missing in my policy? I do not want them to have any other access with accounts, other than this.

After reading the iam, ec2, and rds user guides, and one of the blog posts, I have some questions because I'm a bit fuzzy now after creating the policy, role, and testing it out with one of a test user account. The user actually had full admin access to all resources in the region, which isn't what I wanted.

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx29HCT3ABL7LP3/Resource-level-Permissions-for-EC2-Controlling-Management-Access-on-Specific-Ins

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/sf_env": "dev"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "rds:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/sf_env": "dev"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Did you verify that the user doesn't already have the permissions, when the policy isn't there?

Comment: Yes, user didn't have access to all resources without the policy. I have a new issue. The user cannot stop, terminate, or reboot an instance. I gave the group IAM policy the ability to launch the instance. The instance is tagged with sf_env. I thought the role's iam policy with full ec2 admin access would allow him to do stop the instance or terminate the instance.